# Android ArrayList values

Tags: android

I have an int n which chooses a random number. Each time I save n in arraylist array. Now I want to compare that if int n is equal to two last random numbers. For example if we have      `2 - 3 - 5- 3` , it should choose 3 as a repeated int. Should I compare it them like this?

```
if(n == array.size()-2) { 
}
```

It doesn't work like this. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(n == array.get(array.size()-2)) { 
//some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For comparing last **two integers**,Use:

```
if(n == array.get(array.size()-2) || n == array.get(array.size()-1)) { 
     //do the Logic here if they are Same
}
```